# Magento Custom Button in Order-View Controller URL not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to add a custom button to the order view page. The button shows up fine, but I can't figure out how to direct the button the the controller or if I'm even defining the controller properly in my config.xml . When I try to access the controller manually via url, everything I try gets a 404.

Could someone help me figure out what I'm missing?

I know this question is asked several times, but there is not a single clear or finished answer with the full solution.

local/Siphor/Custombuttons/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Siphor_Custombuttons>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </Siphor_Custombuttons>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custombuttons>
                <class>Siphor_Custombuttons_Model</class>
            </custombuttons>
        </models>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
    <custombuttons>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>Siphor_Custombuttons</module>
            <frontName>custombuttons</frontName>
        </args>
    </custombuttons>
        </routers>
    </admin>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <observers>
                <custombuttons>
                    <class>custombuttons/observer</class>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <method>addButtons</method>
                </custombuttons>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

local/Siphor/Custombuttons/Model/Observer.php

```
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
     if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
        $order_id=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

        if($order->getState() == 'processing')
            {
            $block->addButton('custom_button', 
            array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Button'), 
                'onclick' => "", 'class' => 'disabled' ));

      }else {



        $message = Mage::helper('core')->__('Are you sure you want to do this?');
        $block->addButton('custom_button', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Custom Button'),
            'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('Custombuttons/Adminhtml_Index/rto)}')",
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));
    }
    }
  }
}
```

local/Siphor/Custombuttons/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Siphor_Custombuttons_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    protected function _initOrder()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);

        if (!$order->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return false;
        }
        Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
        Mage::register('current_order', $order);
        return $order;
    }


public function rtoAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->setState('processing', true)
                ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
            );
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }

}

public function shipmentAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->setState('shipment', true)
                ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
            );
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }

}
```

Comment: you should remove this question and add it  as an answer to your previous question. this is not appropriate to post a question when it is an answer you will be flagged soon with moderators and they would remove it, so best is to do it soon.

Comment: This is not a solution, it's faulty. I'm trying to find an answer to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the CSRF security will not allow you to check the URLs to the controller directly. You'll need to disable those under your settings if you want to try to manually access them.

//local/Siphor/Custombuttons/Model/Observer.php

```
    <?php
class Siphor_Custombuttons_Model_Observer
{
    public function addButtons($observer)
    {


        $block = $observer->getBlock();
         if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            $order_id=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
            $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

            if($order->getState() == 'processing')
                {
                $block->addButton('rto', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Button'), 
                    'onclick' => "", 'class' => 'disabled' ));

          }else {

 echo Mage::getUrl('*/button');

            $message = Mage::helper('core')->__('Are you sure you want to do this?');
            $block->addButton('custom_button', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Custom Button'),
                'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('*/button/rto')}')",
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));
        }
        }
      }
}
```

//local/Siphor/Custombuttons/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Siphor_Custombuttons>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </Siphor_Custombuttons>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custombuttons>
                <class>Siphor_Custombuttons_Model</class>
            </custombuttons>
        </models>
    </global>
        <admin>
        <routers>
    <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <custombuttons after="Mage_Adminhtml">Siphor_Custombuttons_Adminhtml</custombuttons>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml> 
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <custombuttons>
                        <class>custombuttons/observer</class>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <method>addButtons</method>
                    </custombuttons>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

//local/Siphor/Custombuttons/Adminhtml/ButtonController.php

```
<?php

class Siphor_Custombuttons_Adminhtml_ButtonController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{

    protected function _initOrder()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);

        if (!$order->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return false;
        }
        Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
        Mage::register('current_order', $order);
        return $order;
    }


public function rtoAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->setState('processing', true)
                ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
            );
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }

}

public function shipmentAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->setState('shipment', true)
                ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
            );
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }

}  }
```